# How to force Apache to release filelocks?

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, httpd

To be honest [I already posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097891/), and on searching for a resolution as no feedback there as yet, this site appeared, and it appears a separate login, so forgive me if I am duplicating across Stack sites but not sure how the visibility works.

Anyway after rendering a file on localhost, on a local machine, I am unable to save the file after editing - the file is locked and noted as being opened by another program. This turns out to be httpd.exe

Is there a directive I can use to force file release or what is occurring here? Using Apache 2.2

Comment: Restarting apache should release the locks ...

Comment: Since posting I have discovered indeed it does. But I want to be able to make changes to files incrementally and test the outcome very regularly - preferably not have to keep restarting Apache. Can this be configured? 

I note by the way I canperform one edit&save only without the lock taking place. Thereafter it is locked until restart.

Comment: What OS are you using? For Windows, there is a number of ways to release file lock, but it's better to understand why lock happens in the first place. What type file are you editing? For example, Apache on Windows has issues with font files: [GD2 Fonts locking on Windows/Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309567/gd2-fonts-locking-on-windows-apache)

Comment: Windows XP. The files I have seen it applying to are html and php files.